# Double moving average in R

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

How do you calculate a double moving average in R? I can't seem to find any documentation for code that allows this. ts_ma is only suitable for monthly/quarterly data but I have weekly. There is a DEMA (double exponential moving average) but I am not sure if this is the same as double moving average? By double moving average, I am looking to apply the moving average technique twice, once to the original data and then to the resulting single moving average data

Comment: I mean, if you can apply it once, can't you apply it again to the result? From your description, I don't understand why you'd need a special function for it?

Comment: It's a standard technique so I'm just confused as to why there isn't a function for it.